# The operator -= is undefined for the argument type(s) double, boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, double

I was developing something. But an error appears, and i cannot fix it.
It says ''The operator -= is undefined for the argument type(s) double, boolean'' on my code:

```
if (x -= 15.0D < 0.0D) {
```

I'm just leaving out a part of my code. Anyone knows how to fix it? I cannot get it work. Thank you :)

Comment: You should be using `if (x - 15.0D < 0.0D)` or better for double comparison `if (Double.compare(x-15d, 0) == -1)`

Comment: @SMA not necessarily: OP could mean `if ((x -= 15.0D) < 0.0D)`. And `Double.compare` is *not* a better way to express this.

Comment: What do you want to subtract from `x` when `15 < 0`? Is that even what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the way [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) is defined in Java, `-=` has lower precedence than `<`; as such, `x -= 15.0D < 0.0D` is evaluated as:

```
x -= (15.0D < 0.0D)
```

or

```
x -= false
```

which is not a valid expression in Java because, like the error says:

> The operator -= is undefined for the argument type(s) double, boolean

The fix depends upon what you are trying to express:

- If you intend to say "subtract 15 from x, then compare x to zero", you can write this as:

  ```
  (x -= 15.0) < 0.0
  ```

  However, conditionals with side effects (e.g. changing a variable's value) are confusing because it's easy to misread them, ignoring the side effect. It is more readable (and I would guess semantically identical) to write:

  ```
  x -= 15.0;
  if (x < 0.0) {
  ```
- If you intend to say "if x - 15 is less than zero", you don't use the `-=` operator, just use plain `-`:

  ```
  if (x - 15.0 < 0.0)
  ```

  Note that inner brackets are not required here, because `-` has higher precedence than `<`.

  But then it's also easier to express this as:

  ```
  if (x < 15.0) {
  ```

Note that you don't need the `.`, `0` and the `D` suffix: provided you have a decimal point in the literal, and don't use the `F` suffix to make it a `float`, a decimal literal is of `double` type.

```
15.   15D  15.0  15.D  15.0D
```

are all valid `double` literals with the same value. (Personally, I prefer `15.0`: I don't like the one ending with a `.`; it looks incomplete to me; and `15D` looks a bit too much like `150`).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the precedence.
In this case the precedence of "<" is more than "-=" hence what you are performing "-=" on is a boolean as the result of the comparison will be a boolean. Hence you are getting the error "The operator -= is undefined for the argument type(s) double, boolean".

Use proper brackets to give a precedence to your "-=" operation to solve it.